# A question about a kind of Chapter Header and Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I'm currently writing a dissertation in report class. I want to modify the Table of Contents in my document. In fact, I apply the following commands:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlength\mylength
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thechapter}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:}
\settowidth\mylength{\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum\hspace{-20pt}}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}
```

So, chapter one in the table of contents is listed as

```
Chapter 1:   Introduction
```

What I would like to see is

```
Chapter First:   Introduction
```

Seems like an easy enough thing to ask for, but can't seem to find a good way to do this. Any feedback would be most appreciative.

Comment: Do you want to have, say `Chapter First` only in the table of contents, or also in the chapter heading?

Comment: @Bernard, I want to have "Chapter First:" only in table of contents.

Comment: That's what I feared… ;o)

Comment: @Bernard, why? this is difficult?

Comment: For me, yes. I'll try to think on how to have  access to the data in the .toc file.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thechapter}` will of course get TeX in an infinite loop.

Comment: @ Piet van Oostrum, what would you recommend to fix the problem?

Comment: remove that line.

Comment: @Piet van Oostrum, how do I create "Chapter First:" in the table of contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to start with. It is independent of `tocloft`, and actually, I don't know how it works with `tocloft`. By the way, for me "Chapter First" instead of "First Chapter" sounds odd, but in another language this could be the proper order.

```
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\let\origcontentsline\contentsline
\newif\ifchaptertocline
\renewcommand{\contentsline}[1]{%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{chapter}}{\chaptertoclinetrue}{\chaptertoclinefalse}
     \origcontentsline{#1}%
}
\let\orignumberline\numberline
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%
     \ifchaptertocline Chapter \Ordinalstringnum{#1}\else#1\fi:\space
}
```

Comment: why using the commands that I mentioned above, the desired result can not be achieved?